# Event Listener not working in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a app where I want to send email to users when a new article is created, so I'm using Laravel Event Listener to build logic.

I added below code in `post` model.

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [ 'created' => SendMail::class ];
```

Below is the code in SendMail Event file

```
class SendMail
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
public function __construct()
{

}
public function broadcastOn()
{

     return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
}
}
```

It seems that Event is triggering because if I added some code in constructor function then it is executing. But I am expecting listener to trigger after creating a successful post.

I also registered with Event and Listener in `EventServiceProvider.php` file.

```
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
    SendMail::class => [
        SendEmailFired::class,
    ],
];
```

I really appreciate any kind of help. I wasted my whole time figuring out the problem but not getting where is the exact issue.

One last thing to mention that I am using Vyogar Laravel plugin.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where the event would fire but the listener wouldn't do anything.
Try to import both the Event class and the Listener class into your EventServiceProvider.php that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a late answer...

You forgot to inherit `ShouldBroadcast` to your new implementation.

```php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class SendMail implements ShouldBroadcast
{
}
```